# No cambia el tema según su elección con shared preferences flutter

Tags: android, flutter, ios, dart

Lo que hice fue con un botón se pueda cambiar el tema de claro a obscuro, y lo hice así:

En un archivo llamado share_preferences hice mi declaración de que variables deseaba utilizar:

```
    class Preferences {
      static late SharedPreferences _prefs;
      static String _user = '';
      static String _password = '';
      static String _employeeName = '';
      static String _department = '';
      static String _employeeNumber = '';
      static int _unlockPreference = 0;
      static bool _isDarkmode = false;
    
      static Future init() async {
        _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      }
    
    static String get user {
        return _prefs.getString('user') ?? _user;
      }
    
      static set user(String user) {
        _user = user;
        _prefs.setString('user', user);
      }
    
      // algunas otras propiedades....
    
      static bool get isDarkmode {
        return _prefs.getBool('isDarkmode') ?? _isDarkmode;
      }
    
      static set isDarkmode(bool value) {
        _isDarkmode = value;
        _prefs.setBool('isDarkmode', value);
      }

     }
```

Entonces mande a llamarlo de la siguiente manera con el botón:

```
final darkNotifier = ValueNotifier < bool > (true); // Declaado despues del extends 

bool isDark = darkNotifier.value; // Declarado despues del widget build , antes del scaffold 
//.....
IconButton(
  icon: toggle ?
  const Icon(Icons.dark_mode): const Icon(
      Icons.light_mode,
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      Preferences.isDarkmode = darkNotifier.value;
      final themeProvider =
        Provider.of < ThemeProvider > (context, listen: false);

      setState(() {
        isDark
          ?
          themeProvider.setDarktMode() :
          themeProvider.setLightMode();
        toggle = !toggle;
        isDark = !isDark;
        darkNotifier.value = isDark;
      });
    }),
```

Para mi ThemeProvider que es el que tiene la estructura donde se elije la configuración, del tema y demás lo hice así :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeData currentTheme;
  ThemeProvider({required bool isDarkmode})
      : currentTheme = isDarkmode ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light();

  setLightMode() {
    currentTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(elevation: 3, color: Color(0xFF4F9A94)),
    );
    notifyListeners();
  }

  setDarktMode() {
    currentTheme = ThemeData.dark();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Ahí justo declare que para el tema claro, este tuviera un color distinto que es el color teal con un degradado.
Y para declararlo en el main y aplique los cambios el ejidos lo hice así:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Preferences.init();
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => ThemeProvider(isDarkmode: Preferences.isDarkmode)),
    ],
    child: const MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({
    Key ? key
  }): super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: 'login',
      routes: {
        //Rutas.....
      },
      theme: Provider.of < ThemeProvider > (context).currentTheme,
    );
  }
}
```

El inconveniente viene así al iniciar,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al aplicar el tema con el botón si lo cambia a negro :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces vuelvo a presionar el botón y lo cambia al color definido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la aplicación cuando la compilo sale como la primera imagen a pesar de que definí un color especifico, cuando cambio el tema a modo obscuro se aplica, reinicio mi aplicación y lo mantiene el inconveniente es que si defino el tema claro a pesar de que tiene definido un color especifico el appbar, aparece asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: disculpa, pero no logro entender muy bien cual es tu problema finalmente. aclárame un poco mas el texto final por favor.

Comment: Ya actualice mi pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que lo que guardas en el preference solo es el flag si es dark o no, más no estás guardando el tema, por lo que tienes que cambiar el valor que usas cuando el tema no es dark, aquí:

```dart
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

// Está iniciando con light(), pero no con tu theme actualizado.
ThemeProvider({required bool isDarkmode})
      : currentTheme = isDarkmode ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light();
```

Podrías hacer esto:

```dart
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

final lightTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(elevation: 3, color: Color(0xFF4F9A94)),
    );

ThemeProvider({required bool isDarkmode})
      : currentTheme = isDarkmode ? ThemeData.dark() : lightTheme;

}
```

También cambiarías aquí para reusar el valor:

```dart
  setLightMode() {
    currentTheme = lightTheme;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tienes razón he estado revisando eso y si aplica